Picklist values are not showing in the LWC Datatable
Here I'm creating custom type Datatable here which extends standard LWC Datatable. Also, creating an extra HTML file customPickList.html, customPickListEdit.html so we can put the Picklist Combobox and its static value here. Below image of the structure.

customDataType.js:
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import customPickListTemplate from "./customPicklist.html";
import customPickListEditTemplate from "./customPickListEdit.html";
export default class CustomDataType extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes= {
        customPicklist: {
            template:customPickListTemplate,
            editTemplate:customPickListEditTemplate,
            standardCellLayout:true,
            typeAttributes:["options","value","context"]
        }
    };
}

My Apex Controller:
public with sharing class OpportunityLineItemController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<OpportunityLineItem> getOpportunityLineItems(String opportunityId) {

        return [SELECT Id,ProductLineItemName__c, UnitPrice,
                Quantity,Discount_Value__c,
                Discount_Type__c,GST__c 
                FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                WHERE OpportunityId = :opportunityId];
    }
}

opportunityLineItemsEditor.js:
import { LightningElement,track,wire,api} from 'lwc';
import { updateRecord, deleteRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import OPPORTUNITYPRODUCT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem'; 
import DISCOUNT_TYPE from '@salesforce/schema/OpportunityLineItem.Discount_Type__c'; 

import getOpportunityLineItems from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityLineItemController.getOpportunityLineItems';

const columns = [
{ label: 'ProductLineItemName', fieldName: 'ProductLineItemName__c'},
{ label:'Quantity', fieldName:'Quantity',editable:true},
{ label: 'Sales Price', fieldName: 'UnitPrice', editable:true},
{ label: 'Discount Value', fieldName: 'Discount_Value__c', editable:true},
{
    label: 'Discount Type',
    fieldName: 'Discount_Type__c',
    type: 'customPickListEdit',
    editable: true,
    typeAttributes: {
        placeholder: 'Choose Type',
        options: discountTypeOptions,
        value: { fieldName: 'Discount_Type__c' }, // default value for picklist
        
    }
},
{ label: 'GST %', fieldName: '  GST__c', editable:true},


{
    type: "button",
    typeAttributes: {
        iconName: "utility:delete",
        name: "deleteOpportunity",
        variant: "destructive",
        iconSize: "x-small",
        class: "small-button"
    }
}

];

export default class OpportunityLineItemsEditor extends LightningElement {

@api recordId;

opportunityLineData=[];
columns = columns;
draftValues=[];
oppLineProp;
discountTypeOptions=[];

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITYPRODUCT_OBJECT })
    opportunityProductInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$opportunityProductInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: DISCOUNT_TYPE
    })
    wiredPicklistValues({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.discountTypeOptions = data.value;
            // Add default option if needed
            // this.discountTypeOptions.unshift({ label: '--None--', value: '' });
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching picklist values', error);
        }
    }


@wire(getOpportunityLineItems,{
    opportunityId:"$recordId"
}) getOpportunityLine(result){
    this.oppLineProp=result;

    if(result.data)
    {
        this.opportunityLineData=result.data;

    }
    else if(result.error)
    {
        console.log('error while loading records');
    }


}

async handleSave(event)
{

    let records=event.detail.draftValues;
    let updateRecordsArray= records.map((currItem) => {
        let fieldInput = {...currItem};
        return{
            fields:fieldInput
        };

    });

    this.draftValues=[]
    let updateRecordsArrayPromise=updateRecordsArray.map((currItem) => updateRecord(currItem));

    await Promise.all(updateRecordsArrayPromise);

    const toastEvent = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Success',
        message:
            'Records Updated Successfully',
            variant:'success'
    });
    console.log('Dispatching toast event...');
    this.dispatchEvent(toastEvent);
    console.log('Toast event dispatched.');
    await refreshApex(this.oppLineProp);

}

async handleRowAction(event) {
    if (event.detail.action.name === "deleteOpportunity") {
        deleteRecord(event.detail.row.Id).then(() => {
            
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: "Record deleted successfully!",
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("error, " + error);
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error deleting record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        })
    }

    await refreshApex(this.oppLineProp);
}

}

opportunityLineItemsEditor.html:
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Opportunity Line Items">
        <template if:true={opportunityLineData}>
            <lightning-datatable
            key-field="Id"
            data={opportunityLineData}
            columns={columns}
            onsave={handleSave}
            draft-values={draftValues}
            onrowaction={handleRowAction}
            hide-checkbox-column></lightning-datatable>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>

Here, Discount_Type__c is a picklist field, but its records are not showing in the datatable. What mistake might I be making, and what would be the workaround to resolve this?

The wiredPicklistValues wire adapter retrieves the available picklist values for the Discount_Type__c field. However, you're not directly assigning the retrieved data.value to the discountTypeOptions property. Instead, you're potentially overwriting it with an empty array in the if block.
Workaround:
Directly assign the retrieved picklist values:
JavaScript
@wire(getPicklistValues, {
    recordTypeId: '$opportunityProductInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId',
    fieldApiName: DISCOUNT_TYPE
})
wiredPicklistValues({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.discountTypeOptions = data.value;
    } else if (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching picklist values', error);
    }
}

Use code with caution.
content_copy
(Optional) Add a default option if needed:
JavaScript
if (data) {
    this.discountTypeOptions = data.value;
    // Add default option if needed
    this.discountTypeOptions.unshift({ label: '--None--', value: '' });
}

Use code with caution.
content_copy
By directly assigning data.value to discountTypeOptions, the datatable will have access to the retrieved picklist values for rendering the Discount Type column.
Additional Considerations:
Make sure you're handling potential errors in the wiredPicklistValues wire adapter.
If you need to add a default option like "--None--", do it after assigning the retrieved values to ensure user-defined options aren't overwritten.
With these changes, your datatable should display the available picklist options for the Discount_Type__c field.

Thank you for the answer.
